# Cryptic Vagrant upgrade message

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I get this when I do vagrant up:

```
A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '0.4.4'. The latest is version '0.5.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
```

$**vagrant box update**

```
==> default: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    default: Latest installed version: 0.4.4
    default: Version constraints: >= 0.4.0
    default: Provider: virtualbox
==> default: Updating 'laravel/homestead' with provider 'virtualbox' from version
==> default: '0.4.4' to '0.5.0'...
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.
```

What do I do next to update laravel/homestead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hum ... weird, did you retry, I just tried locally as I also have for now `0.4.4` and

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/laravel$ vagrant box update
"/Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/laravel"
==> default: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    default: Latest installed version: 0.4.4
    default: Version constraints:
    default: Provider: virtualbox
==> default: Updating 'laravel/homestead' with provider 'virtualbox' from version
==> default: '0.4.4' to '0.5.0'...
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead'
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.5.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 1% (Rate: 476k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:45:06)
```

so working here. can you check if you can download the [box file](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box) directly ?

Comment: Thats what I did to overcome. Thanks for running through the example. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the way the updated box was built. For more info on versioning, see [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html). But since

> updating the machine requires destroying it and recreating it, which
>   can cause important data to be lost...

You might be better off just creating a new Vagrant file and porting over your data (which hopefully is in an external volume). You should also make sure it's worth updating, check: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

Also check you have the latest versions of Vagrant and VB.